# Tracking UserID for Optional Login Site in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Analytics along with Google Tag Manager and I would like to add userID tracking to my site. My site has a login feature, but it is not required to view most of the pages. What would I assign as the user id for users who do not log into the site at all?

I initially thought that I could just give the userID variable a value of none, but I'm afraid that would cause all the users to be aggregated into one user on google analytics. When you add a userID does it replace the randomly generated clientID as the unique tracking identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the userId feature in Google Analytics you have to create a special view that shows only users with a userID.

Per Googles TOS you must not persist the userID if a user is not currently logged in. So you would not pass any value at all.

In absence of a userID Google Analytics will default to use the clientID for aggregation.